# Postgresql 9.5 Performance degradation when updating JSON field using jsonb_set

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have a performance problem when using jsonb_set to replace values of a jsonb field.

It seems that every time the values are replaced in the JSONB expression the time updating the field increases.

This is my test table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP_package_var(
    id      VARCHAR,
    val     jsonb
);
```

My test function is:

```
create or replace function set_package_var_any(package_name text, var_name text, var_subname text, var_value anyelement) returns VOID as $func$
DECLARE
  wk_var jsonb;
  wk_mainvar jsonb;
  wk_newvar jsonb;
  wk_name text := lower(var_name);
  wk_subname text := lower(var_subname);
  start_at timestamp;
  end_at timestamp;
BEGIN
        select val from TEMP_package_var INTO wk_var WHERE id = lower(package_name);
        if not found then
           insert into TEMP_package_var(id, val) values(lower(package_name),jsonb_build_object(wk_name, jsonb_build_object(wk_subname, var_value)));
           return;
        end if;
        wk_subname := var_name || ',' || wk_subname;
        start_at := clock_timestamp();
        UPDATE TEMP_package_var SET val = jsonb_set(wk_var, string_to_array(wk_subname,','), to_jsonb(var_value), true) WHERE id = lower(package_name);
        end_at := clock_timestamp();
        raise notice 'UPDATE Time__________________________________________: % - [%]', end_at - start_at, var_value;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

And my main function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pkgvar_set_test(loops bigint, rerun bigint) returns void as $body$
declare
    start_at timestamp;
    end_at timestamp;
begin
    start_at := clock_timestamp();
    for ix0 in 1 .. rerun loop
        for ix in 1 .. loops loop
            perform set_package_var_any('package_name', 'var_name', 'var_name_'||to_char(ix,'FM00000'), 'var_value_'||to_char(ix0,'FM00000')||'_'||to_char(ix,'FM00000'));
        end loop;
    end loop;
    end_at := clock_timestamp();
    raise notice 'time is %', end_at - start_at;
end;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Then I execute the main function several times.

**The test looks like this:**

```
select pkgvar_set_test(2,2);
```

This create the following JSONB row:

```
{"var_name": {"var_name_00001": "var_value_00001_00001", "var_name_00002": "var_value_00001_00002"}}
```

And then replaces the values:

```
{"var_name": {"var_name_00001": "var_value_00002_00001", "var_name_00002": "var_value_00002_00002"}}
```

**But when doing the same test with more records**

First time:

```
select pkgvar_set_test(50,50);
NOTICE:  time is 00:00:00.667468
```

Second time:

```
select pkgvar_set_test(50,50);
NOTICE:  time is 00:00:01.348275
```

Third time:

```
select pkgvar_set_test(50,50);
NOTICE:  time is 00:00:01.920818
```

And so on, as you can see replacing is getting slower and slower.
I understand the difference between the first loop and the second loop, but what I cannot figure it out is why the value increases with the number of executions.

Can somebody help me out?

```
Postgresql: 9.5.2
OS: Centos 7.1
```

Thank you